# The functionality of 'onclick' for a button in Android in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, button, audio

I’m currently working in Flutter to develop an app in language learning. Previously, I had developed a similar app for Android in Android Studio. In that app I had buttons which when clicked would produce a local audio file in the form of a short spoken sentence. I would like to have a similarly functioning button in Flutter. I’ve been looking for quite a while now but without succes. Right now, when I click I get no audio.I’m now looking for help. I would really appreciate some advice on this matter.
Thanks. Code:

```
  import 'package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart';
  import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';

    class Lesson1Viet extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _Lesson1VietState createState() => _Lesson1VietState();
  }

  class _Lesson1VietState extends State<Lesson1Viet> {

    AudioCache _audioCache;
    @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
      // create this only once
      _audioCache = AudioCache(prefix: "assets/", fixedPlayer: AudioPlayer()..setReleaseMode(ReleaseMode.STOP));
    }
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[350],
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Lesson 1"),
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey[600],),

        body:   ListView(
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  Image.asset('assets/hotel_reception_program_istock.jpg',
                    width: 350,
                    height: 300,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  FlatButton(onPressed: () => _audioCache.play('assets/mijnopname.mp3'),
                    child: Icon (Icons.arrow_right) ,
                    color: Colors.grey[400],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Divider(
                height: 60.0,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),

              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly ,
                children: [
                  Image.asset('assets/guest_at_reception.png',
                    width: 100.0,
                    height: 100.0,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 100.0,),
                  Image.asset('assets/receptionist_male.png',
                    width: 100.0,
                    height: 100.0,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  Text('            Hello.',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                      )
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 100.0,),
                  Text('Hello and welcome.   ',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                      )
                  ),
                ],
              ),

              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  ButtonTheme(
                    minWidth: 50.0,
                    height: 10.0,
                    child: RaisedButton
                  (onPressed: () => _audioCache.play('assets/hello_and_welcome.mp4'),
                    child:Icon(Icons.arrow_right),
                   color: Colors.grey[400],
                      ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width:100.0),
                  ButtonTheme(
                    minWidth: 50.0,
                    height: 10.0,
                    child: RaisedButton
                  (onPressed: () => _audioCache.play('assets/hello_and_welcome.mp4'),
                    child: Icon(Icons.arrow_right),
                    color: Colors.grey[400],
                      ),
                     ),
                    ],
                   ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  Text('         Xin chào.',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                      )
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width:100.0),
                  Text('Xin chào và chào mừng.',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                      )
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Divider(
                height: 60.0,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  Text('          Thank you.',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                      )
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 100.0,),
                  Text('           How may I help you?',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                      )
                  ),
                ],
              ),

              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  ButtonTheme(
                    minWidth: 50.0,
                    height: 10.0,
                    child:
                    RaisedButton(onPressed: () => _audioCache.play('assets/hello_and_welcome.mp4'),
                      child: Icon(Icons.arrow_right),
                      color: Colors.grey[400],
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 100.0,),
                  ButtonTheme(
                    minWidth: 50.0,
                    height: 10.0,
                    child:
                    RaisedButton(onPressed: () => _audioCache.play('assets/hello_and_welcome.mp4'),
                      child: Icon(Icons.arrow_right),
                      color: Colors.grey[400],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),

              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  Text('          Cảm ơn bạn.',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                      )
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width:100.0),
                  Text('Làm thế nào để tôi giúp bạn?',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                      )
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Divider(
                height: 60.0,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                RaisedButton(onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>
                        SimpleRecorder()),
                  );
                },
                child: Icon(Icons.arrow_right),
                  color: Colors.grey[400],
                  ),
              ],
            ),
           ],
        ),
      );

    }
  }
```

Comment: Plz show some code

Comment: Rstrelba, please note that I have include the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a [GestureDetector](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html) wrapped around your widget like so,

```dart
GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          // your function here.
        },
        child: MyWidget()
      ),
```

or you can use [InkWell](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html) to get the ripple effect aswell like so,

```dart
InkWell(
  onTap: () {
    // your function here.
  },
  child: MyWidget()
)
```

For audio, take a look at [audio players](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers).

Answer (score 0):

First, why not use https://pub.dev/packages/assets_audio_player ?
Second, why play local files? Why not loading it from an internet?
Third, you are using mix of mp3 and mp4 files. Last is video, I do not think it played by audio library you use.